# Why doesn't OpenGL draw a polygon in this code?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

Here is the simplest code, but it does not represent anything. That isn't possible.
 Everything seems to be absolutely correct. However, I only see a black background.
 It used to work all the time, but now it doesn't.
 The color is correct and the blue triangle should be visible. But nothing.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

constexpr auto FPS_RATE = 60;
int windowHeight = 600, windowWidth = 600;

void init();
void displayFunction();
void idleFunction();
double getTime();

double getTime()
{
    using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        ).count();
}

const double frame_delay = 1.0 / FPS_RATE;
double last_render = 0;

void init()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunction);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-windowWidth / 2, windowWidth / 2, -windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 2);
}

void idleFunction()
{
    const double current_time = getTime();
    if ((current_time - last_render) > frame_delay)
    {
        last_render = current_time;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void displayFunction()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3i(0, 0, 1);

    glVertex2i(-50, 0);
    glVertex2i(50, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 50);
    glVertex2i(100, 50);

    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - windowWidth) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - windowHeight) / 2);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your polygon is not a triangle.  The two triangles of the polygon face different ways, so your quadrilateral is twisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is [`glColor3i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

When you would use

```cpp
glColor3f(0, 0, 1.0f);
```

then you would see a full blue colored polygon. But when you want to use `glColor3i`, then the color has to be set to

```cpp
glColor3i(0, 0, 2147483647); // 2147483647 == 0x7fffffff
```

to get a polygon with the same blue color.

When you use the the version of `glColor` with integral signed arguments, like `glColor3b`, `glColor3s` or `glColor3i`, then the full range of the integral value is mapped to the floating point range [-1.0, 1.0]. So for `glColor3i` the integral values in range [−2.147.483.648, 2.147.483.647] are mapped to [-1.0, 1.0] (See [Common integral data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types)).

The unsigned version of `glColor` like `glColor3ub`, `glColor3us` or `glColor3ui` maps the integral values to the range [0.0, 1.0]. e.g `glColor3ub` maps the arguments from [0, 255] to [0.0, 1.0].

Comment: Thanks. Do not tell me how I can specify colors in RGB format, in the range of 0...255? With glColor3ub()?